# undefined method `isolation_level' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, isolation-level, nomethoderror

Where does the call to the isolation_level come from?

My module fails at `a.save!`

```
module AppsHelpers      
  def self.create_app!
    a = App.new
    a.save!
    a
  end
end
```

The specific NoMethodError:

```
 Failure/Error: @app = AppsHelpers::create_app!
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `isolation_level' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
```

What could possibly cause this failure?

System:

- ruby 1.9.3p448
- Rails 3.2.8

Comment: Is `App` an ActiveRecord model? There's a built-in `create` method that does exactly what your `create_app` method does.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `AppsHelpers.create_app!` instead of the `::`?

Comment: Can you post the code for App? That's were the problem is. You stack trace should give you more information

Answer (score 0):

This was simple. I was calling a method defined in the [Transactional Isolation gem](https://github.com/qertoip/transaction_isolation): The stacktrace was not helpful because I was calling it from an installed gem and this was a missing dependency.